# would you trust important files to SD card - after hard stopping DD procedure by pulling card out

Tags: sd-card

I've SD card which I basically tortured. Used it as boot drive for server, than I screwed it up few times while attempted to DD to it using terminal from bigger hard disk - which got stuck, and I pulled out from read - after having it reformatted in windows because grep couldn't reformat it... allot of torture allot of errors.

But now it seems to be fine, except that it's 8gb memory is like 6gb total now.

I found a great place for it, after all the sadism - I put it as a swap storage for server (mostly 0% usage).

I'm planning to use it also for apache www directory for my personal projects. I'm working on wp plugins for example. But I'm afraid it's too risky, considering all the trouble it went through!

is there something I can do to check its integrity?
would you trust this card few month of sleepless nights and coding?

Comment: This is almost as bad as a shopping question. Indeterminate past workload, indeterminate present workload, indeterminate future workload . . . .

Comment: @ surfasb - +1. Almost sounds like life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what your media is (SD Card, Hard disk, etc.), no matter how "tortured" or brand new it is -- never trust anything of importance to it. **Always, always** have a backup.

Making a simple copy of your data to a different media is so cheap: burn a DVD, or copy your data to DropBox, it is very easy if your dataset is small (personal projects). After you copied your files and *verified your backed up copy is ok*, you don't need to worry about how good/reliable your media is. You need to periodically update your backup, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't. Why bother? THese cards are so cheap now.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and I wouldn't trust the card either as it shows signs of degradation (25%broken).